# How to write projection info into netcdf file use xarray?

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, cartopy, python-iris

I need to use `xarray` to write the projection information into the netcdf file so that `Iris` can directly obtain the projection information when reading it.

We know that there are many projection s in cartopy, such as equal latitude and longitude projection, Lambert projection, etc.  How to write this information into netcdf file?  Is it similar to an epsg string?

Comment: You can add a PROj4 string as an attribute to the xarray. It will be written as meta data to the netcdf4 file.

Answer (score 1):

For Iris, you most likely want to encode the grid projection information in a `grid_mapping` attribute on the data variables according to the [Climate and Forecasting netCDF Conventions](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.8/cf-conventions.html#grid-mappings-and-projections).